# HBase PeriodicMemstoreFlusher exception

Tags: exception, hbase

I run HBase cluster and see in the log file every 10 seconds this exception:

```
2015-12-30 20:18:10,160 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer$PeriodicMemstoreFlusher: Caught exception java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.next(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3436)
    at java.util.Collections.min(Collections.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getEarliestFlushTimeForAllStores(HRegion.java:1572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.shouldFlush(HRegion.java:1904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer$PeriodicMemstoreFlusher.chore(HRegionServer.java:1509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:87)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Maybe someone knows what does it mean? 
Looks like HBase bug.

Can you point me to the bug fix?

HBase version is 1.0.0-cdh5.4.8

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PeriodicMemstoreFlusher will run into the following exception. lastStoreFlushTimeMap is populated for families, if there is no family in the table or there is no entry in lastStoreFlushTimeMap.

Hope this helps!!